# Python-Merge sort difficulties

Tags: python, mergesort

I attempted to implement a merge sort, here is my code:

```
def mergeSort(array):
    result=[]
    n=len(array)
    if n==1:
        result=array
    else:
        a=round(n/2)
        first=mergeSort(array[0:a])
        second=mergeSort(array[a:n])

        for i in range(len(first)):
            for j in range(len(second)):
                if first[i]<second[j]:
                    result.append(first[i])
                    i=i+1
                else:
                    result.append(second[j])
                    j=j+1
    return result

a=[5,4,1,8,7,6,2,3]
b=mergeSort(a)
print(b)
```

Unfortunately, the result turns out to be `[1]`. What is wrong with my function?

Comment: Just a quick tip, unrelated to the question. Python has a enumerate, instead of using `for i in range(len(my_list))`, use `for i, value in enumerate(my_list)`, it unpacks the value and also assign a index (starting at 0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A number of things...

Firstly, this is a recursive function, meaning you cannot create a list within the function, as you did here:

```
result=[]
```

This will simply reset your list after every recursive call, skewing your results. The easiest thing to do is to alter the list that is passed as a parameter to merge sort.

Your next problem is that you have a for loop within a for loop. This will not work because while the first for loop iterates over `first`, the second for loop will iterate over `second` for every increment of `i`, which is not what you want. What you need is to compare both `first` and `second` and extract the minimum value, and then the next minimum value, and so on until you get a sorted list.
So your for loops need to be changed to the following:

```
while i < len(first) and j < len(second):
```

Which leads me to final problem in your code. The while loop will exit after one of the conditions are met, meaning either `i` or `j` (one or the other) will not have reached `len(first)` or `len(second)`. In other words, there will be one value in either `first` or `second` that is unaccounted for. You need to add this unaccounted value to your sorted list, meaning you must implement this final excerpt at the end of your function:

```
remaining = first if i < j else second
r = i if remaining == first else j

while r < len(remaining):
    array[k] = remaining[r]
    r = r + 1 
    k = k + 1
```

Here `r` represents the index value where the previous while loop broke off. The while loop will then iterate through the rest of the remaining values; adding them to the end of your sorted list.

You merge sort should now look as follows:

```
def mergeSort(array):
    if len(array)==1:
        return array
    else:
        a=round(len(array)/2)
        first=mergeSort(array[:a])
        second=mergeSort(array[a:])
        i = 0
        j = 0
        k = 0
        while i < len(first) and j < len(second):
            if first[i]<second[j]:
                array[k] = first[i]
                i=i+1
                k=k+1
            else:
                array[k] = second[j]
                j=j+1
                k=k+1

        remaining = first if i < j else second
        r = i if remaining == first else j

        while r < len(remaining):
            array[k] = remaining[r]
            r += 1; k += 1

    return array
```

I tried to not alter your code as much as possible in order to make it easier for you to understand. However, if your difficulty in understanding what I did persists, try de-bugging your merge sort using multiple print statements so that you can follow the function's progress and see where it goes wrong.